# Cannot change color of a-tag

Tags: jquery

My demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/4w3Hy/3/

My first code adds html to an div with the id:Content:

```
$(".text").click(function() {
 $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
});
```

On the id:Content, with the new html, i try to run another jquery function:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
 $('.click').css('color','');
 $(this).css( "color", "red" );
});
```

But somehow this wont work!! What did i made wrong? to see html http://jsfiddle.net/4w3Hy/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events to elements dynamically appended to the DOM.  In the original code the `.click` element is not present on the DOM at the time the `click` event handler is attached to all elements with the class `.click`, therefore the event is never bound to the new element.

Using `on()` allows us to attach the event handler to a parent such as the `document` already available on the DOM.  `.click` elements are then appended to the `document` and when clicked fire a click event that propagates to the `document`.  Once the `document` receives the `click` event it will determine if the event was fired by an element with class `.click`, if so it will execute our attached event.  If you are familiar with the deprecated `live()` method, you pretty much understand the concept.

Normally, it would be best to attach to a static parent closer to the `.click` element, however since I did not have your entire HTML markup, I used `document`.

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html()); });

$(document).on("click", ".click", function() {
    $('.click').css('color','');
    $(this).css( "color", "red" ); });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4w3Hy/5/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4w3Hy/9/)**

```
$(".text").click(function() {
    $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
    $(".click").click(function() {

    $(this).css( {color:"red" });
});
});
```